# Incrementing Array Index on button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Below is my javascript code! I'm trying to increment the index of array **$arr** everytime the user clicks a button. The array is defined in a separate php tag! Where am I going wrong?

```
function option1() {
var i = 0;

document.getElementById("btn0").value = "newButtonValue";
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = 
"<?php echo $arr["results"][i++]["question"] ?>"; 
}
```

Comment: *Where am I going wrong?* `var i=0` is inside `option1` and it is initialized to `0` every time `option1` is invoked.

Comment: here `<?php echo $arr["results"][i++]["question"] ?>` you are mixing an Array in the backend with an index in the frontend. The two are executed *(and therefore available)* at different times and on different computers.

Comment: @Thomas if I add an integer instead of **i++** the code runs fine!! It just wont take a variable in the square brackets i.e in [i++] or even [i]

Comment: @ZaidWaseem because with the static integer, this is all php code now and runs solely in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your compiler return output to browser your php code was compiled and you can't run it such as javascript.

you can use this js:

```
var arr  = <?php echo json_encode($arr["results"]);?>;

function option1() {
    var i = 0;

    document.getElementById("btn0").value = "newButtonValue";
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = arr[i++]["question"];
}
```

Comment: I'd extract the `var i=0;` out of the function, or the `i++` is pointless

Comment: That's right. check arr[i++] index for undefined bug too.

Answer (score 0):

> .html file

```
<button onclick="addIndex(this)" queNo="0">newButtonValue</button>
```

> in .js file

```
function addIndex(btn) {
    var i = btn.getAttribute("queNo")
    console.log(i);
    btn.setAttribute("queNo", i++);

    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "<?php echo $arr['results']["+i+"]['question'] ?>"; 
}
```

Hope it's help you